The Reactor "Context" can only be seen by operators above it
reading about Context in Reactor https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context, in order to simulate the variables we used to set in ThreadLocal scope, Reactor has the concept of Context. I attach below an image of the reactor documentation about this Context and an example. Its said that this Context is set to the Subscriber object that is created during subscription. Its said too that this Subscriber goes from downstream to upstream because it cannot be other way in order for the Producer to have this Subscriber in order to call it. Along the way the Subscriber flows from bottom to top in the pipeline its executed first the contextWrite methods in order to set the Context in the created Subscriber.
As mentioned in the documentation of Reactor it is said the next but I dont understand it technically speaking:


Why in the below example of Reactor documentation, I dont have access to the Context in the Mono.deferContextual if the contextWrite method has been executed and has put this key in the Subscriber?.


